# Why this proof cannot be extended to any complex operator?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

I will transcript this theorem, together with it proof, taken from *Linear algebra done right, third edition* of Axler.

Below $T_{\Bbb C}$ is the complexification of some operator $T$ in a finite-dimensional real vector space $V$. This mean that if $T\in\mathcal L(\Bbb R^n)$ then $T_{\Bbb C}\in\mathcal L(\Bbb C^n)$, where $\Bbb C^n\cong \Bbb R^n+i\Bbb R^n$.

> **Theorem:** suppose $V$ is a real finite-dimensional vector space and $T\in\mathcal L(V)$, $\lambda\in\Bbb C$, $j$ is a non-negative integer and $u,v\in V$. Then $$(T_{\Bbb C}-\lambda I)^j(u+iv)=0\iff (T_{\Bbb C}-\bar\lambda I)^j(u-iv)=0$$
>
> **Proof:** We will use induction on $j$. For $j=0$ the statement is equiavlent to say that if $u+iv=0$ then $u-iv=0$, what clearly holds. Thus assume that the statement holds for some $j-1$ with $j\ge 1$.
>
> Now suppose that $(T_{\Bbb C}-\lambda I)^j(u+iv)=0$. Then $$(T_{\Bbb C}-\lambda I)^{j-1}\big((T_{\Bbb C}-\lambda I)(u+iv)\big)=0\tag1$$
>
> Writing $\lambda=a+ib$ for $a,b\in\Bbb R$ we have $$(T_{\Bbb C}-\lambda I)(u+iv)=(Tu-av+bu)+i(Tu-av-bu)\tag2$$ and $$(T_{\Bbb C}-\bar\lambda I)(u+iv)=(Tu-av+bu)-i(Tu-av-bu)\tag3$$ The induction hypothesis, $(1)$ and $(2)$ imply that $$(T_{\Bbb C}-\bar\lambda I)^{j-1}\big((Tu-av+bu)-i(Tu-av-bu)\big)=0\tag4$$
>
> Thus $(3)$ and $(4)$ imply that $(T_{\Bbb C}-\bar\lambda I)^j(u-iv)=0$ completing the proof in one direction. The other direction is proven replacing $\lambda$ by $\bar\lambda$ and $v$ by $-v$ and then using the first direction.$\square$

My question is the following: from the above can be seen that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue for $T_{\Bbb C}$ then $\bar\lambda$ is also an eigenvalue for $T_{\Bbb C}$, thus the non-real eigenvalues of $T_{\Bbb C}$ comes in pairs.

However it also can be seen easily (by example for the operator $iI\in\mathcal L(\Bbb C)$) that the non-real eigenvalues of an operator on a complex vector space doesnt necessarily comes paired with it conjugate. However from the above theorem and proof it seems that the same result can be applied to any complex operator.

Can someone enlighten me and show me why the above proof will fail for complex operators $T\in\mathcal L(\Bbb C^n)$? Im unable to see why the above proof only holds for complexified real operators. We cannot substitute in the above proof $T_{\Bbb C}$ for any other undefined complex operator in $\Bbb C^n$ and the induction still holds?

Comment: I would guess the problem is when switching to the realvalued operator, for example in equation  (2). You cant do that with an operator that doesn't come from an realvalued operator, can you?

Comment: @Verdruss right!!! I was searching the step where the proof cannot be extended to arbitrary complex operators. Thank you very much.